# Integrating CakePHP Auth with Facebook Connect (Webtechnick Plugin)

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, plugins, authentication

I am using Webtechnick's Facebook Plugin - but I am not having any luck getting it to authenticate with $this->Facebook->login().

None of the callbacks are being called:

- afterFacebookLogin()
- beforeFacebookSave()
- beforeFacebookLogin()

I am not sure exactly where to start, so any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We would need to have some more information, for instance: how are you trying to connect yourself to facebook, is there any other configuration you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the change of Facebooks authentication mechanism. It has since been fixed, and seems to work now.

Comment: Which version of cake and facebook plugin are you using?? It's not working for my on cakephp 2